# Show alert view when click on a link

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uialertview

I use formatted text in UIWebView, i have something like this:

```
<a href="tel://0442059840">0442059840</a>
```

I need to show alert to the user when clicking on that link using the `UIAlertView` for confirmation before launching the telephone call. Is this possible? Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but you need to use undocumented method for this. Search on google or stackoverflow you will find it easily. Here is a link for helping you.

http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development/iphone-sdk-tip-firing-custom-events-when-a-link-is-clicked-in-a-uiwebview/

Answer (score 6):

Override the delegate method

```
webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
```

and do the cjhanges as in the code I added.

Following code may help you :

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = [request URL];
    NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];
    if([urlString isEqualToString:@"tel://0442059840"])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Title", nil)
                                                        message:NSLocalizedString(@"Message", nil)
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil)
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
    return YES;
}
```