# Query about UIWebview

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview

HI am making a application in which the the user enter data into text field(url) and that url is opened in the webview below that .Now when the user clicks on any link in the webview that we have opened then can i get the address of the clicked url (the url which user clicked on the webview) as i need to update(display) that url into texfiled above , so that user can come to know which url is being opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

delegate for your purpose.

like

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *requestedUrl = [request URL];
    //use requestedURL methods
        // like yourtextbox.text = [requestedUrl absoluteURL];
       //don't forget to return YES :)
       return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is an undocumented method. See my answer in the post [Show alert view when click on a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593991/show-alert-view-when-click-on-a-link/6594194#6594194)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, UIWebView has some delegate methods which can help you with this:

Check this one

```
– webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
```