# How to push a view from a web page?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Suppose my app will load a local web page which is stored in my app bundle. I want to push the view or present a view when the user click a link or an image inside that web page. How to do this? Let's make this be general question: how to communicate with my app from a local web page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "webview.request.URL.absoluteString" to get the request-string of the clicked link in the delegate-method "webViewDidFinishLoad:" or "webViewDidStartLoad:".
then you can scan this url for some special substring.

For example you could make a link like ".../index.php?iPhone_action=abcdef".
In the delegate-methods you  can check if the link has the substring "?iPhone_action=" and if it does, then put the part of the link, whick follows "?iPhone_action=" in a NSString.
(in our example it would be "abcdef").
Depending on the value of this NSString you could fire a action in your app.

Answer (score 0):

There is an undocumented method to catch the event when you click on a link in UIWebView. You can do whatever you want to do in that method.Search on google/stackoverflow for it. Or see my answer in this stackoverflow post.

[Show alert view when click on a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593991/show-alert-view-when-click-on-a-link/6594194#6594194)